# zsh delete subdirectory with wildcard in path

Tags: wildcard, zsh, filepath, rm

For a directory structure of:

```
└── bar
    ├── first
    │   └── tmp
    └── second
        └── tmp
```

I want to delete all `tmp` directories.
However,

```
rm -rf 'bar/*/tmp/'
```

does not delete the directory

```
ls bar/*/
```

still retrurns both `tmp` directories:

```
bar/first/:
tmp

bar/second/:
tmp
```

Comment: Works for me when you just remove quote marks from `rm`: `rm -rf bar/*/tmp/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem here is the single quotes

```
rm -rf 'bar/*/tmp/'
```

if you remove them you'll be fine.

```
rm -rf bar/*/tmp
```

The reason for this is that single quotes in (most, if not all) shell languages indicates that the contained string of characters is to be treated entirely as a string, which ignores the globbing you are trying to do.